# Till and up to difference

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> I will stay in Singapore from Monday till Thursday.
>
> I will stay in Singapore form Monday up to Thursday.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say "from Monday till Thursday" is better than "from Monday up to Thursday".

**With "till" you mark the departure date**.

As for "up to", it can mean "until", especially in British English (according to the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/up-to)):

> - Those conferences produced many quantified development goals for periods *up to 2015*.
> - The United Nations statements and documents released *up to now* are ambiguous.

However, if you are talking about the days of the week, you'd better avoid "from ... up to". But "from Monday to Friday" is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

"I will stay in Singapore from Monday till Thursday"

This is a valid sentence and "till" means the same as "until", although till is an older word and not in common usage. Most people assume till is a shortened version of until, although that's not actually the case.

"Up to" is not a valid usage in this scenario.

Two alternate versions are

I will stay in Singapore from Monday untilThursday.

I will stay in Singapore from Monday to Thursday.